# iPhone - Casting string to unsigned char

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsstring

I am trying to decrypt a string from the server.

And I want the string in following part -

```
unsigned char Cipher1[] = {My String};
```

My string is

> "194,75,26,184,223,124,164,170,161,213,135,46,160,5,82,46,56,44,244,116,37,20,181,65,49,243,172,203,32,188,168,54,46,207,126,14,111,24,39,131,185,13,58,105,32,168,77,83,202,165,242,198,34,192,161,39,202,58,230,72,234,218,171,50,187,235,124,24,16,2,117,188,221,73,136,37,81,217,30,17,57,136,91,224,178,12,37,255"

How to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
const unsigned char *string = (const unsigned char *) [MyString UTF8String];
```

Comment: Hi , I am getting error - Invalid Initializer. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to convert an NSString to a char *, use `- (const char *)cStringUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

```
const char *cipher1 = [myString cStringWithEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: it's `– cStringUsingEncoding:`, not with `+`